# Printing window with GtkTreeView in C?

Tags: c, printing, gtk

I have some reports in my application that are represented as window with GtkTreeView widget reading data from GtkListStore model. These reports are much like Excel tables with usual stuff: column names, some header and footer text, maybe small image, ...

What should I use/read/learn to be able to print this, having in mind that I am a C programmer using GTK+ and I want code to be portable to Linux and Windows.

Can you give me some tips what is best way to do this and maybe put some (pseudo or real) code?

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible with [libCairo](http://cairographics.org/), it supports many [backends](http://cairographics.org/backends/) such as Windows GDI, PostScript and PDF.

Sure, that doesn't spawn a printing dialog but that should not be very complicated if the data to be printed can be computed automatically in all important formats. I think Mozilla Firefox does printing with libCairo, too.